# How to set spacing on GWT CompositeCell?

Tags: gwt

I'm not sure if it's a valid question but I have a `CompositeCell` as a parameter to construct `DefaultNodeInfo`, which is a part of `TreeViewModel`.

Basically, the `CompositeCell` looks like this:

```
Tree item1[button1]
    Tree item2[button2]
    ...
```

Now I want to set spacing between tree items and buttons:

```
Tree item1  [button1]
```

I'm not sure how to achieve this. Maybe `CompositeCell` is not the right one for me because it doesn't have `setSpacing` method?

But I need a Cell anyway to construct a `NodeInfo`.

========================================

Let me make my question clearer.

The only `Widget` I have is a [CellTree](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html?locale=en#!CwCellTree). To construct a `CellTree` I need to provide a `TreeViewModel`:

```
  cellTree = new CellTree(
      new SomeTreeViewModel(), null);
```

To construct a `TreeViewModel` I need to provide `DefaultNodeInfo`. In another word, to override the following method in `TreeViewModel`:

```
  public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(final T value)
```

To construct a `DefaultNodeInfo`:

```
  public DefaultNodeInfo(AbstractDataProvider<T> dataProvider, Cell<T> cell)
```

I have to provide a `Cell` (finally comes to my question...)

`Cell` is not a `Widget` but only an interface.

Here I need a `CompositeCell` which contains a `AbstractCell`:

```
  Tree item1
```

and a `ButtonCell`:

```
  [button1]
```

The `CompositeCell` will look like this:

```
  Tree item1[button1]
```

I want to set style on either `ButtonCell` or `CompositeCell` or any `Cell` to add the spacing:

```
  Tree item1   [button1]
```

I don't think apply css on `CellTree` will help because it only affects the style of the tree but not the tree items...

Actually I found a workaround but I don't think it's encouraged, which is to override `ButtonCell`'s `render` method:

```
                public void render(final Context context, final SafeHtml data,
                        final SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
                    sb.appendHtmlConstant("<button type=\"button\" tabindex=\"-1\" style=\"margin-left:10px;\">");
                    if (data != null) {
                      sb.append(data);
                    }
                    sb.appendHtmlConstant("</button>");
                }
```

Any other thoughts?

Comment: I have a workaround which is to override ButtonCell's render method. But it doesn't look cool...

Comment: Why don't you use CSS to do it?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Yeah but you still have to override render, don't you? I'm not sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a CSS class to you cell, or a widget that contains it. For example:

```
.myCell input, .myCell div {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Then

```
cellTree.setStyleName("myCell");
```

Comment: I know css will work but I just don't see a way to apply css on Cells, e.g. ButtonCell, EditTextCell, because there's no setStyleName or similar methods in Cell. I'm quite new to GWT so any example is appreciated.

Comment: Add the style which I suggested to the parent widget of your cell. If you add this cell to a panel, use myPanel.setStyleName("myCell").

Comment: As I said, add this style to a widget to which you add your cell. You have to attach it to something.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I've updated my question. Hope this time it's clearer.